# Replace one character with another using PHP function

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace, str-replace

I need to use a custom PHP function to process this data,

```
Austin Metro>Central Austin|Austin Metro>Georgetown|Austin Metro>Lake Travis | Westlake|Austin Metro>Leander | Cedar Park|Austin Metro>Round Rock | Pflugerville | Hutto|Austin Metro>Southwest Austin
```

and convert it so that it reads like this:

```
Austin Metro>Central Austin#Austin Metro>Georgetown#Austin Metro>Lake Travis | Westlake#Austin Metro>Leander | Cedar Park#Austin Metro>Round Rock | Pflugerville | Hutto#Austin Metro>Southwest Austin
```

Currently using the following but is also replacing the character "|" between "Leander | Cedar Park". Is there a way to only replace the ones with no space before or after?

```
 preg_replace("/|/", "#", {categories[1]} );
```

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you're looking for is called a look ahead/behind [assertion in PCRE](http://php.net/regexp.reference.assertions). Specifically you want a negative look behind and negative look ahead for space surrounding your pipe. Also you should note that the character `|` has special meaning in PCRE so you **need** to escape it to get a literal.

```
preg_replace('/(?<! )\|(?! )/', '#', $str);
```

The `(?<! )` is a negative look-behind. It says match the character `|`, but only if it is not proceeded by a space. The `(?! )` is the negative look ahead. It says match the character `|` but only if it is not followed by a space.